# SELECT INTO variable named temp table, reference it, And DROP it

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How does one create a variable named temp table using SELECT INTO (e.g. `#TempTable2017_12_18_14_32_423` where `#TempTable` is a string and `2017_12_18_14_32_423` is a `GETDATE()` formatted variable) and then reference the same name in after it has been created? I then need to drop it again after the procedure is completed.

I know it would be possible with Dynamic SQL but I am trying to avoid it due to the complexity of the entire process and need to limit time spent on this project converting it to Dynamic SQL

Comment: Why do you think you need such complexity in your temp table names? temp tables are local to just your own session and they'll be dropped automatically if they're created within a stored procedure when that stored procedure finishes executing.

Comment: I greatly dislike comments like "Why...", but I couldn't resist - why do you need such named temporary tables? /sry, Damien was much quicker/

Comment: The sp runs a few hundred times a minute and need to avoid dropping the tables prematurely

Comment: Each instance of the SP that runs will get its own temp table to work with even if all of them use the *exact same name*.

Comment: And in the case of triggers? I know I asked about sp but have a similiar problem there too.

Comment: This smells... Your temp tables will have the same structure - at least you don't state something else. You can define a temp table with the same name over and over as long as they are living in different sessions. But in your case you might think about a "normal" table with kind of a `SessionID` column. This would allow each process to find the corresponding set of rows and can be truncated/dropped easily. Whenever I see *the same object but many different names* I know there's something wrong...

Comment: Seems like a good solution. I will have a go at that.

Comment: The bottom lines if you can't create a temp table with a variable name outside of a dynamic Query.  At least as far as I know. T-SQL and Stored Procedures are very limited when it comes to what you can do with variables outside of dynamic queries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are thinking of such complex ideas. What you are looking for by having the tables named after the date and time is to filter the records based on that, then the best way is to have a datetime column on the table and then filter the records based on that column.

Normally when you create a temp table the table is actually created in the temdb of the server. And even if you are just specifying the table name as #temp, the table create on tempdb will have some additional information with the table name like the session id, that's why you can have multiple temp tables with the same name on the same databases on multiple query window (Session) with the different structures.

(The concept is too broad to explain here. So I'm just giving a basic idea)

Comment: I understand your point and know this already but the process being run needs the complexity as it uses AI to determine one of about 50 tasks to perform.